# MarkLogic Data Hub Framework for Real-time Processing

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

It seems Marklogic DHF is purpose built for batch processing and I'm looking for some guidance to extend that to real-time ingestion from IBM MQ and later harmonize it to canonical entities. This post [How to use marklogic database for real time processing of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720088/how-to-use-marklogic-database-for-real-time-processing-of-data) talks about triggers & CPF mechanism. How well they both fit in DHF as I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the docs on [Ingesting via the Java Client API](https://marklogic-community.github.io/marklogic-data-hub/ingest/marklogic-client-api/). This describes our realtime use case for data loading while also allowing you to harmonize the data.